# How can i create a scheduled event in a SAM Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pipeline, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have this and it is functional

```
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: 'rate(5 minutes)'
            Enabled: false
```

I had to remove the Name: because the pipeline would fail with builds due to the event already existing

But isn't this going to create another event every time?

Is there o way to tell it to use the event if it's already in the stack or create one if there isn't one?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure But I'm afraid there is no way to use existing resource with SAM structure. I've migrated my lambdas to SAM and it required everything to be created from scratch. Since SAM is heavily dependant to Cloudformation, it wants everything to be created by itself. Here is a solution, maybe you wanna group up resources to sam files according to schedules. One Cloudformation stack for 5 min schedule, another for 10 min schedule etc.

Comment: Interesting
I don't mind not being able to use existing one. I only want not to fail my builds :) And also it would be nice to not have useless resources created continuously. Do you think that it would make sense to Name the resource but make sure to delete it (if it exists) before creating it with each build?

Comment: I don't know what your structure is, but I were you, I would probably give a unique name to each schedule in each sam structure rather than not giving any. Because if you don't give a name, Cloudformation will be creating a schedule name by combining some logical some random characters such as lambda-x-scheduleuh289312y8312bdsd something. it's better which one is which by looking the name :) By the way, each deployment trigger for the same SAM structure should not be trying to create a new schedule. It will use the existing one in its Cloudformation Stack.