# How can i add more policies to my Lambda if there is a Statement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I added this under properties

```
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ses:SendEmail'
              - 'ses:SendRawEmail'
            Resource: '*'
```

It works, but i also want to add - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole but i get an error if i add it under Policies at the same level with Statement, before or after

Is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of an IAM role that includes specific SES permissions and also leverages the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy.

```
MyLambdaRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
    ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: ses-access
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ses:SendEmail
              - ses:SendRawEmail
            Resource: *
```

Comment: that's exactly what i needed wow! I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132328/how-can-i-create-a-scheduled-event-in-a-sam-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment125742429_71132328), if this is on a pipeline, will that not attempt to create a resource that already exists with every build? If so, is there a way to tell it to just use the existing one, or to first remove it before creating it again?

Comment: Typically a CI/CD pipeline is created once and then it runs automatically whenever you commit source changes. You don't keep re-deploying the pipeline.

Comment: Oh that's awesome so it only gave me an issue because of the resource i had first created in the console, but its good to know that it will not be a problem with the pipeline xD. Cheers!